# Decoder with mutually exclusive properties

Tags: fp-ts

Using the `Decoder` API, is there a way to define a decoder with mutually exclusive properties?

```
import * as D from 'io-ts/Decoder';

const decoder = pipe(
  D.struct({
    a: D.string
  }),
  D.intersect(
    D.partial({
      b: D.string,
      c: D.boolean
    })
  )
);
```

The above sets up a situation where `b` and `c` can both be present, but are optional. How could I instead require that one of `b` or `c` *must* be present, but not both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Union combinator](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/Decoder.md#the-union-combinator).

```js
const decoder = pipe(
  D.struct({
    a: D.string
  }),
  D.intersect(
    D.union(
      D.struct({ b: D.string }),
      D.struct({ c: D.string })
    )
  )
);
```

Bear in mind that you won't be able to access `b` or `c` without first checking if those properties exist, since Typescript doesn't have a way to know which one of the two is present in your object.

```js
type Decoder = D.TypeOf<typeof decoder>
declare const myDecoder: Decoder;

myDecoder.a // inferred as `string`
myDecoder.b // TYPE ERROR: Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; } & { c: string; }'
myDecoder.c // TYPE ERROR: Property 'c' does not exist on type '{ a: string; } & { b: string; }'

if ("b" in myDecoder) {
  myDecoder.b // inferred as `string`
}

if ("c" in myDecoder) {
  myDecoder.c // inferred as `string`
}
```

Notice how, when checking for both the mutually exclusive properties, you get a type error. TypeScript correctly infers that it's a case that can never happen (`myDecoder` is inferred as `never` inside the `if` block)

```js
if ("b" in myDecoder && "c" in myDecoder) {
  myDecoder.b // TYPE ERROR: Property 'b' does not exist on type 'never'.
  myDecoder.c // TYPE ERROR: Property 'c' does not exist on type 'never'.
}
```